# wordpress blog posts's time

Tags: date-time, blog-page

I want to show the blog posts'time like below:

"A heading title , posted by XYZ, 1 hour ago"

I want the time that says: 5 minutes ago, 1 hour ago, 2 days ago 1 month ago like that.

how can i get this working?

i can't get the exact wordpress API code to implement it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template where you see `the_title()`, you will want to change it to something along the following:

```
echo get_the_title() . ', ' .
    'posted by ' . 
    get_the_author() . ', ' .
    human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) . 
    ' ago';
```

[`human_time_diff()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff) is the one doing the part regarding your topic. Though you also asked for the others.

However, if you want it to look even cleaner, try:

```
printf(
    '<h2>%s, posted by %s, %s ago</h2>',
    get_the_title(),
    get_the_author(),
    human_time_diff( 
        get_the_time( 'U' ), 
        current_time( 'timestamp' )
    )
);
```

Replacing whatever tag/formatting you want in the first parameter